# Series and integrals convergence and divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Can someone suggest an example of continuous functions on an interval $[1, +\infty)$ for which the integral 
$$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$$
converges and the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$$
diverges and vice versa? What properties should such functions have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of such function is  $f(x)=\cos(2\pi x)/x$. Then
$$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx=-\text{Ci}(2\pi)\;\text{is convergent}\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=+\infty$$
where $\text{Ci}$ is the [Cosine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral).

Vice versa, for $f(x)=|\sin(2\pi x)|$,
$$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx=+\infty\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0=0.$$
I don't know a general statement. The property does NOT hold if $f$ is non-negative, continuous and monotone decreasing (see [Integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)).

Comment: Hm, thanks you very much. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$. Then $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ is convergent (Fresnel integral) but $(f(n))$ is not convergent, hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ is divergent.